# How do I show that $I-P$ projects vectors outside $C(A)$ and $N(A^{T})$ to $N(A^{T})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. Let $C(A)$ and $N(A^{T})$ respectively denote the column space and left null space of $A$. Also, $I$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix.

Suppose $P$ is the projection matrix that orthogonally projects to $C(A)$. I'm trying to prove that $I-P$ projects to $N(A^{T})$.

Here is my attempt:

If $x \in C(A)$, then $(I-P)x = x - Px = 0$, which means $A^{T}(I-P)x = 0$, and hence $(I-P)x \in N(A^{T})$.

If $x \in N(A^{T})$, then $(I-P)x = x - Px = x - 0 = x$, and hence $(I-P)x \in N(A^{T})$.

So I've shown that $I-P$ projects all vectors in $C(A)$ and $N(A^{T})$, to $N(A^{T})$. How do I show that vectors outside those two subspaces are also projected to $N(A^{T})$? I cannot yet use the fact that every vector in a vector space can be written as the sum of two vectors from two subspaces which are orthogonal complements.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507116/i-p-projection-matrix) question, one of the answers does what I've done above and claims that it is enough to prove that $I-P$ projects every vector to $N(A^{T})$. If that's the case, why is it enough to only consider vectors from $C(A)$ and $N(A^{T})$?

Comment: The dimension of $C(A)$ and the dimension of $N(A^T)$ sums to $m$.

Comment: @P.Quinton: Sorry, but could you elaborate on what that implies in this context?

Comment: It means that linear combinations of elements of $C(A)$ and $N(A^T)$ spans $\mathbb R^m$. So any $x=y+z$ with $y\in C(A)$ and $z\in N(A^T)$. The rest of the proof is the same as yours.